# Non interactive authentication to Azure AD for CRUD operations on Sharepoint Project Server

Tags: rest, azure, sharepoint

I need to connect to a Sharepoint OData to do some CRUD operations (from SAP C4C).

The API endpoint is https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Site}/_api/ProjectServer/Projects

I was able to create a Token doing a JWT with grant_type=client_credentials and a certificate (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) but the I can't access the data on ProjectServer/Projects. The error is this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "ProjectServerError(s) LastError=GeneralNotLicensed Instructions: Pass this into PSClientError constructor to access all error information"
        }
    }
}
```

I think i need to authenticate to Azure AD with a user but i can't find a good way to do it without interaction from a user.

I tried the Password Grant flow (grant_type=password using a service user) but it doesn't seem to work (the Token endpoint give me a error: "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password").

I don't have access to any azure connector from the platform i'm using so i have to do all operations manually...

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks.

Edit:

I attach the password grant call if it can be useful:

```
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_GUID}/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
scope=openid {clientid} offline_access
resource=https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com
client_id={clientId}
username={user}@hosttenant.com
password=password
```

The response is:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password\r\nTrace ID: XXXXXXXXXX\r\nCorrelation ID: XXXXXXXX\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-27 15:36:50Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70002,
        50126
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-08-27 15:36:50Z",
    "trace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "correlation_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: I use CSOM for this as I'm using .NET so I need a SharePointOnlineCredentials object that takes a username (string) and SecurePassword (not a plain password string).  This seems to be heading in the right direction for direct access to the API via ODATA though https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27a7869b-1390-4d8e-8cc3-4199d37d0fe6/what-is-the-supported-way-to-authenticate-to-odata-on-project-online?forum=project2010custprog

Comment: The error seems clear: `AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password`. Have you logged in as the service user to e.g. portal.office.com? Remember that it may require you to set a new password.

Comment: @juunas The user is active and i can login to both portal.office.com and https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Site}/. The user is sharepoint administrator (for development purposes)...

Comment: @codebrane It seems to use a federated authentication to get the fedauth cookie... maybe i could re-implement it if i can't find anything more easy/clean...

Comment: Pretty sure ROPC grant requires a client secret as well.